# instalation ffmpeg in Ubuntu

Tags: php, apache-http-server, ubuntu, ffmpeg

I am using following steps for installing ffmpeg-php extension in Ubuntu

1. Download ffmpeg-php-0.5.2.1.tbz2
2. extract it
3. go to this directory
4. run this "phpize"
5. ./configure && make

but when I am running step 5 I got this error message "ffmpeg shared libraries not found. Make sure ffmpeg is compiled as shared libraries using the --enable-shared option
"

what to do please someone help me I am fresher in Linux

I already install ffmpeg in this machin using this steps 
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Now I am installing extension for PHP

using this steps from this http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/

INSTALLATION

Comment: ffmpeg-php is ancient and has not been updated for ages. It will not work with any recent FFmpeg code. Try [​PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/) instead and also see [Using FFmpeg from PHP Scripts](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20FFmpeg%20from%20PHP%20scripts).

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of the phpize but the error you are getting is because system is not able to locate the ffmpeg libraries. Just update you commands like this,

```
./configure --enable-shared --prefix=/home/chintan/out.dir - (change the install directory accordigly)
make
make install - This will install all the libraries in /home/chintan/out.dir/lib directory
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/chintan/out.dir/lib
```

And do the other required steps where you are getting the error.

If you don't give --prefix argument in configure and execute make install the libraries will be copied in to /lib directory of your system.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sir I tried this also , what is my problem .......

first I install Ubuntu but somehow I did not get Repo for php-devel and ffmpeg-devel

then I install redhat and Now I got php-devel and ffmpeg-devel repo in to this 

FYI:(
my PHP version is 5.1.x and php-devel virsion is 5.6  and php-ffmpeg virsion is 5.3 )

Now when I compile the ffmpeg source then it can be compile but with error

Answer (score 0):

Run these following commands in SSH

```
# echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
# echo "/usr/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf
# ldconfig
```

Then, try to configure again,